# Hash mark removes pretty url part

Tags: php, html, jquery-ui, .htaccess

I'm trying to figure something out, but can't seem to find the reason why, and I'm rather confident it's something stupid, so I'm posting it here to get a bit of help.

I'm using URL rewriting to redirect URL's to the correct page. The only rule I actually have is:

```
RewriteBase /~bart/website
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_/\-\+|]+)$ index.php?m=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which redirects pretty much everything to index, which is fine, as that is how the system works.

Now I call this url:

```
http://localhost/~bart/website/admin/list_content/edit/activiteit/1
```

This one works pretty well, but then comes the problem.

The page that is returned contains a jQuery UI tabber with 3 tabs. The tab headers consist of links like `<a href="#tab1">Tab1</a>` which is the standard format for jquery UI tabs that do nothing fancy. The only problem is that clicking those leads to:

```
http://localhost/~bart/website/#tab1
```

This is a different page in the eyes of my browser and as such it load the new page (my main page) instead of a new tab on the old page.

I can't for the life of me figure out what the reason it, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why does the browser send a request to the server at all? A link like `#tab1` should make him jump to the anchor named `tab1`. JQuery probably intercepts the click, but it shouldn't request the server too, at least not with a hash mark in the URL.

Comment: Can we see a full snippet of the html. Is the jQuery Tab actually working visually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wild guess, but maybe you have a `<base href="http://localhost/~bart/website/" />` in your HTML? This could confuse the browser.

Comment: Seems your wild guess was entirely correct. I've put that there on time, then entirely forgot about it (lots of html) and it seems it gives some problems here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a  HTML tag (for the relative urls of css and scripts), then your relative urls are relative to the url of  tag instead of the current page url.

Use the absolute URL in the href.